# mysql_list_tables into foreach array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is it possible to list my tables into a foreach array?

current code.

```
 $browsers = array ("site1", "site2", "site3");
 foreach($browsers as $browser) 
 {
  $domain = $browser;
  include ('code.php');
 }
```

Comment: Can you evaluate a little bit, like what are you trying to achieve. And what are these tables? html, database?

Comment: If he's trying to use mysql_list_tables(), then it's tables in a database. I'm pretty sure he's trying to loop through the listed tables and do something with the names, as I've elaborated on below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to do something like this:

```
<?php
$db_name = "your_db_name";
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name");

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $array[0];
    //Or do other stuff with the table name
}
?>
```

That will get a list of the tables in the DB, put them into an array, recurse through the array, and echo the names.

Of course, before you run this, you have to use mysql_pconnect() to connect to the database.

Comment: almost worked, this got it going

$res = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM table");
$tables = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
$tables[] = "$row[0]";
  
$domain = $row[0];
  include ('code.php');
}

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure exactly what you were trying to do, so I tried to guess. Glad you got it working though.